# Unexpected regex results with polytonic Greek capitals

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to select only capital letters in polytonic Greek text using regex. The specific application is PHP, but I had trouble with it so I started playing around with it in RegExr:

https://regexr.com/6ellt

`([Α-ΩΗΙΟΥΩᾼῌῼΡΆΈΉΊΌΎΏᾺῈῊῚῸῪῺἈἘἨἸὈὨᾈᾘᾨἌἜἬἼὌὬᾌᾜᾬἊἚἪἺὊὪᾊᾚᾪἎἮἾὮᾎᾞᾮἉἙἩἹὉὙὩᾉᾙᾩῬἍἝἭἽὍὝὭᾍᾝᾭἋἛἫἻὋὛὫᾋᾛᾫἏἯἿὟὯᾏᾟᾯΪΫᾹῙῩᾸῘῨ])`

When the JavaScript engine is selected, the behaviour is as expected. However, if I select PCRE not only are capital letters selected, but also a bunch of seemingly random lowercase letters.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here? Is this a bug? Is there a way to get the desired result using the PCRE engine?

Comment: Use the u modifier.

Comment: If you use https://regex101.com/r/HIWFeP/1, you will see the matches are the same. In code, you will need to supply the modifier like `u` or  a PCRE verb `(*UTF)` in the regex. `(*UTF)[Α-ΩΗΙΟΥΩᾼῌῼΡΆΈΉΊΌΎΏᾺῈῊῚῸῪῺἈἘἨἸὈὨᾈᾘᾨἌἜἬἼὌὬᾌᾜᾬἊἚἪἺὊὪᾊᾚᾪἎἮἾὮᾎᾞᾮἉἙἩἹὉὙὩᾉᾙᾩῬἍἝἭἽὍὝὭᾍᾝᾭἋἛἫἻὋὛὫᾋᾛᾫἏἯἿὟὯᾏᾟᾯΪΫᾹῙῩᾸῘῨ]` highights the correct matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your answer and explanation.

Comment: Just FYI, regex101 has the Unicode support built in and on by default, it also confuses people as what works there does not work in the code if they do not use the `u` flag.

Comment: BTW, the answer is below, I provided a more compact way to match uppercase Greek letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the PCRE regex engine the input is to be parsed as a Unicode string.

In a PCRE regex, you can prepend the  pattern with a `(*UTF)` verb. The `(*UTF)[Α-ΩΗΙΟΥΩᾼῌῼΡΆΈΉΊΌΎΏᾺῈῊῚῸῪῺἈἘἨἸὈὨᾈᾘᾨἌἜἬἼὌὬᾌᾜᾬἊἚἪἺὊὪᾊᾚᾪἎἮἾὮᾎᾞᾮἉἙἩἹὉὙὩᾉᾙᾩῬἍἝἭἽὍὝὭᾍᾝᾭἋἛἫἻὋὛὫᾋᾛᾫἏἯἿὟὯᾏᾟᾯΪΫᾹῙῩᾸῘῨ]` highights the correct matches.

However, you can also make it a bit shorter with

```
(*UTF)(?=\p{Lu})\p{Greek}
```

Here,

- `(*UTF)` - a PCRE verb telling the PCRE engine the input is a Unicode string
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - a positive lookahead requiring the next char to be an uppercase char
- `\p{Greek}` - a Greek char.

Note in case there is a `u` flag support in your PCRE implementation, it is most probably the way to go (as in PHP, `/(?=\p{Lu})\p{Greek}/u`).